# Is there a simple way of assigning instance variables in a Python class?

Tags: python, python-2.7

When defining a class in Python 2.7, you feed in variables to an init() function, then assign these to instance variables using e.g `self.x`

```
class NewClass(object): 
  def __init__(self, x, y):      
    self.x = x                    
    self.y = y
```

If using a large number of variables, is there a way to simplify this process i.e. not have to explicitly define each instance variable?

Or is there a good reason why they are explicitly defined?

Comment: Sure, but you probably should define them all explicitely anyway. Furthermore, if you are really getting a bunch of variables where this becomes a pain, it's probably time to ask yourself "should this data just go in a container?"

Comment: That looks pretty simple to me. Anything you might change would only complicate things.

Comment: [**`collections.namedtuple`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) is possibly the class @quamrana means, although it's part of the standard library, not a built-in.

Comment: If this were python 3, then `SimpleNamespace` https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace would be enough. Else look up Alex Martelli's Bunch Class http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52308-the-simple-but-handy-collector-of-a-bunch-of-named/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`collections.namedtuple`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) is useful if you want something immutable:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> NewClass = namedtuple('NewClass', 'x y')
>>> obj = NewClass(x=10, y=14)

>>> obj
NewClass(x=10, y=14)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class NewClass(object): 
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.validate(kwargs) # optional      
    self.__dict__.update(kwargs)
```

but the whole idea is kind of smelly

you could additionally have a static set with admissible  `kwargs` keys and `validate` would check if passed `kwargs` contain a subset of that set

Comment: That is more concise but I would dispute that it is simpler.

Comment: **very** smelly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__dict__`:

```
class NewClass:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.headers = ["var{}".format(i+1) for i in range(len(args))]#optional, can use an list of variable names you are expecting
        for a, b in zip(self.headers, args):
            self.__dict__[a] = b
```